# komodo edit cursor 'between' not 'on'?

Tags: ide

I'm using Komodo edit 8.5 on windows 8 and I'm finding it impossible to use. let me illustrate why using the 'pipe' symbol (|) for the cursor.

If I am typing on version an earlier version it would type like any app would ie: ms word or txt pad will let me type between characters as:

**if(|)** ... and I begin to type an x **if(x|)**

where as on version 8:

**if(x|**

the cursor destroys characters in front of it.

I normally write encapsulating brackets then press left to enter into them to begin to give my condistion, this is not helpfull. how do I get this to behave?

also the cursor is an underscore in version 8 wtf's with that!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a problem with Komodo Edit. You have switched your cursor to "insert" mode. Look on your keyboard for a key labeled "Ins" or "Insert" (for me it is on the number pad, right next to the right arrow). Hitting this key toggles the mode of the cursor.